# Suche nach einem Wort

Tags: etymology, single-word-request, vocabulary

Jemand ist dafür, das alle Lebewesen nicht überleben.

Answer (score 1):

Sofern ein Adjektiv gesucht ist, schlage ich *biozidal* vor.

- [*bio-*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/bio-): das Leben oder Lebewesen betreffend
- [*-zid*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/-zid): tötend oder vernichtend
- *-zidal*: zur Tötung oder Vernichtung neigend (analog zu *suizidal* oder *genozidal*)

**Edit:** Wie richtigerweise angemerkt wurde, trifft das Lexem *-zidal* den Sachverhalt noch nicht, da *zur Vernichtung neigend* nicht das Gleiche ist wie *der Wunsch, dass etwas nicht überlebt*.

Comment: Leuchtet nicht ein: 1. Wenn es kein Lebewesen ist, kann es doch sowieso nicht "getötet" werden? 2. Von Töten war nicht die Rede, sondern von dem Wunsch, dass Wesen nicht überleben, z.B. man gönnt ihnen das Aussterben. -- Das ganze ist keine Wissensfrage.

Comment: @Alazon, zu 1.: Es geht in der Frage ganz explizit um Lebewesen. Zu 2.: Stimmt, das ist nicht das Gleiche. Allerdings scheint mir der Sachverhalt „Wunsch, dass Wesen nicht überleben“ viel zu komplex, als dass man ihn mit einem einzigen Lexem ausgedrücken könnte. Und die Anmerkung mit der Wissensfrage verstehe ich nicht: Es wird ein Wort gesucht; ich habe eines vorgeschlagen, das eventuell passen könnte; nicht mehr und nicht weniger.

Comment: Wenn die Antwort darin besteht, Wörter zu erfinden, ist es keine Wissensfrage, meinte ich.